# Decoupling pdf rendering into a reusable assembly / using different rendering strategies

Tags: c#, design-patterns, application-design

We have two apps: desktop client & mvc backend. Both apps have printing functionality. And it's quite obvious that we're repeating ourselves with that. Let me explain this. The routine looks as follows:

1. User enters his ID / sends his data to the mvc endpoint;
2. We check the db if all necessary data is valid;
3. We compose a viewmodel (mvc) / dto (desktop) object;
4. As a requirement there are two type of documents to be printed;
5. Then we make identical calls to a PDF-rendering API (we use PdfSharp) composing two documents.

I think it would be better if we had that pdf-composing logics in a separate assembly. Then it could be reusable. The problem with this is that documents use slightly different properties (data). As a solution we can use one shared dto with all necessary properties:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Render(DocumentDto document) {
    // ioc
    foreach(var strategy in this.strategies) {
        if(strategy.CanRender(document)) {
            yield strategy.Render(document);
        }
    }
}
```

We can also inject DbContext object into our startegies. And each strategy would request the desired properties on its own:

```
public class StrategyA {
    // I'll omit ctor here
    private DbContext db;
    public string Render() {
        // make db calls
        // render the document
    }
}
```

But I don't think this is a good solution either since it requires a db dependency.

Can we design it so that each strategy only uses its own set of properties?

Comment: Why not just pass the data directly into the Render method as opposed to something with a DB dependency?

Comment: @James_Parsons can you illustrate / extend your suggestion?

Comment: Basically, take whatever your domain model is (since I have no idea, let's day say a db call returns an `IEnumerable<object>` and then have the `Render` method accepts that data directly ie, `Render(IEnumerable<object>)` that way, the only dependency is domain model as opposed to your db directly

Comment: How about you create one Render service that takes different document types as different overloads, and applies the correct strategy? Since you have different types for the MCV part and for the desktop client part, you can just use the type system to take care of choosing the right method if you use overloads

Comment: @James_Parsons Good point. Yet the required data spans across multiple entities.

Comment: @lexeme you could still pass multiple entities into the method, or try transforming the data before passing it